# How to change Unity Launch screen image! not Splash screen! Example Shown below

Tags: unity-game-engine, splash-screen

So I have Unity Pro version 2017. What is bugging me is that I removed the splash screen however when I launch the app there is a startup screen that happens before the splash screen, and this start up screen is default color is Unity. It's just a blank image with color, now this is a common thing as sometimes on Appstore apps I see the same screen, and then I make sure the following app was made using Unity. How can I remove this Static blank image on launch?

This is the Image that gets are shown:- 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your project for Android/iOS phones? 
You MUST have a splash screen on a mobile project (not sure for iOS, but it's definitely so on Android), be it the default one or a custom one, so if you're not setting one the engine will automatically set it for you.